# query fields all NULL after inner join

Tags: mysql

Im doing a rather simple mysql query to get an organisation and based on that organisation get their address info and based on address info get their telephone number.

```
select 
organisations.name, organisations.section, 
organisations.department, organisations.address_id, 
addresses.address1, addresses.address2, addresses.city, 
addresses.contact_id 

from organisations 
inner join addresses on organisations.address_id = addresses.id
#inner join communications on addresses.contact_id = communications.id
```

The first join works great for all the info, but for the contact_id it shows all NULL fields (even though they are filled in). I need these to get the next join to work.

result =
http://i.gyazo.com/f7ff46e1e1d5f9253899d50aa27f079c.png

Fields are filled =
http://i.gyazo.com/db82aa41c97d5ddb49f07caabcc45ee2.png

Comment: Can you give a sample data to see?, you have to know the difference between [inner, left,right joins](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ydUTsFd11Ok/UiV8EKJezWI/AAAAAAAACUQ/-pWSuWnv4yU/s1600/sql%2Bjoins.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.hightech-post.com/2011/07/self-join-in-sql-server.html&h=760&w=966&tbnid=QamJzD-4sm9EsM:&tbnh=144&tbnw=184&usg=__otbeU7VfMiVJUC5qBGhCQ48VSCk=&docid=2G4_WREHZ3-QTM&itg=1&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ9QEwAGoVChMI26Km-YOSxwIVwjk-Ch1SvgK1)

Comment: Thank you I will read up on it. Sample data is in screenshot in edited post.

Comment: Add one if the joined ids to the select list, query addresses for that id and see if contact_id is indeed null on one row

Comment: found it thanks to your comment, thank you.